# Authentication : Facebook user access token validation on server side?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

A lot of questions here are talking about validation process of `Facebook access token` on the server side. I am bit confused how is still secure?

My client and server flows are:

1. User `Continue with Facebook` using `Mobile SDK` on the client side.
2. Facebook returns `User access token` to the client side.
3. Server endpoints receive `user access token` (via POST method) and validate the `access_token` using `Graph` API.
4. In case of authenticated user return the `JWT` authorization token in response
5. In the meantime (within an hour), If hackers find out the `endpoint` and pass the new `access_token` to the hacked endpoint.

What will happen if `5th` point gets executed? It's difficult to hack the `POST` parameters but it might be possible after decompiling the app and see the classes file (At least for android apk). In this case, Server will not recognize the forged request and will always return the `JWT Authorization` token to make further calls.

The validity of Facebook `access_token` is 60 days. Do I need to provide an extra layer of security at the time of validation endpoint to make sure that the request is only coming from the application?

Is `facebook user access_token` always changing whenever a user is requesting to sign in?

Any kind of help would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Pretty Much you have to use your own Auth Mechanism lets say Basic Auth. Or an authentication header which is not available for any one apart from the developer.

Comment: @KhushalChouhan Basic auth is not secure because it sends the parameter in clear text.

Comment: I didn't know that. Can you provide the source of your information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Generated `access_token` will always belongs to an App. To verify it pass the `access_token` and `app_token`in:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
&app_token=APP_TOKEN
```